# why ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream can find file but Class.getResourceAsStream can not

Tags: java

[image]

why `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream` can find file but  `Class.getResourceAsStream` can not
just like pic see.

`Class.getResourceAsStream` has first `getClassLoader` and then use `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream`

Comment: Please include the code as text in your question, instead of as an image. Note that the arguments to `Class.getResourceAsStream` and `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream` should generally be different - `Class.getResourceAsStream` gets a resource *relative to that class*.

Comment: Please, paste the source code instead of an image. Theses 2 methods use different path: relative for the class(uses the package as current folder )  and absolute for the classloader. for the class use getResourceAsStream("/yourporperties") to lookup on root.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation of [Class.getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)):

> This method delegates to this object's class loader.
>   ...
>   Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the given resource name using this algorithm:
>
> - If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'
> - Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
>
> `modified_package_name/name`
>
> Where the *modified_package_name* is the package name of this object with '/' substituted for '.'

that is, the difference between both methods: the package name being added.

Probably - I cannot read the image - the given file is not in the same package as the class, so it is not being found.

Answer (score 2):

- The **ClassLoader** uses an absolute path; a full path. No preceding `/`!
- The **Class.getResource** uses a relative path to the class's package folder, or an absolute path if preceded with a `/`.

So for Class.getResourceAsStream a `/` was missing in front.

The *rationale* is that resources for a class could be organized to be stored locally at the package of the class. A ClassLoader only knows full class paths.

Mind also that `getClass().getResourceAsStream(relativePath)` might apply that relativePath to a child class!

Comment: That last sentence is a very good point.  I cringe whenever I see getResource or getResourceAsStream called on the result of getClass() instead of being called on a class literal like `MyApplication.class`.